# How to split one column into multiple colums using T-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

```
ID  NAME         Address1                    Address2
1   kjp     Station raod anand                 NULL
2   Roma    7000 ny street ny 21075            NULL
3   rony    5001 oak tree st jessup 21005      NULL
```

ANd I want Result like

```
ID  NAME         Address1        Addres2    postalcode
1   kjp     Station raod           Anand     NULL
2   Roma    7000 ny street         ny        21075  
3   rony    5001 oak tree st       jessup    21005
```

Comment: what is the logic for the split? just everything following the last space `' '` ?

Comment: There are whole jobs/careers around this type of data transformation.  There isn't a silver bullet solution and IMO is too broad for this information exchange.

Comment: @xQbert You are also into reverse address and geolocation field?

Comment: mainly ETL.  I have to do lots of data cleansing activities on the garbage in  :P  So not just address/geo coding.  I get anything and everything. structured/unstructured and have to "make it work" :P

Comment: @xQbert I want to play a litle bit with string manipulation and found a solution for this particular case :)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing an address can be tricky.

One option is to automate a process using the GOOGLE API to geocode the address, parse the JSON results to return a more standardized results.  This could be time consuming, but you will have more confidence in the data.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvainia%20Ave,%20Washington%20DC
```

Comment: @Krushit I agree don't try to parse address find a parsing engine to do it for you!

Comment: I think this is likely to give the best results.

Comment: @xQbert I agree.  Once we resolved the base data, we only have to process the daily adds.  We were going to pay for the extra volume and hit rate, but it turned out unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

- I **[find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703/3470178)** a function to split the string by space.
- Using **[REVERSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx)** find out the last two words on each string.
- Checking `[last]` and `[beforeLast]`:

  - Can calculate how many chars remove from `[Addres1]`
  - Can determinate if `[last]` is Numeric then that mean `[beforeLast]` will be `[Address2]` other wise `[last]` is `[Address2]`
  - Can determinate if `[last]` is Numeric then I have a zip code.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/RBRP25416)**

```
WITH lastToken as (
    SELECT [ID], 
           ( SELECT REVERSE(s)
             FROM  dbo.SplitString(REVERSE(Address1), ' ')
             WHERE zeroBasedOccurance = 0
           ) as last,
           ( SELECT REVERSE(s)
             FROM  dbo.SplitString(REVERSE(Address1), ' ')
             WHERE zeroBasedOccurance = 1
           ) as beforeLast
   FROM T1
)    
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, 
       LEFT(T1.[Address1], 
            LEN([Address1]) -
            CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(last) = 1
                 THEN LEN(last) + LEN(beforeLast) + 2
                 ELSE LEN(last) + 1 
            END
           ) [Address1],
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(last) = 1
            THEN beforeLast
            ELSE last
       END as [Address2],       
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(last) = 1 
            THEN last
       END as [zipcode], 
       T2.*       
FROM T1
JOIN lastToken T2
  ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: except not all zipcodes are numeric and if it's the 5-4 notation you have a - or not.

Comment: @xQbert arent zipcodes 5 digits?

Comment: in the USA 5 or 5-4 such as 38192-3813 (not a real example) in canada it's #Z#-#Z# for 6 characters 3x3.  in other countries they also vary.

Comment: @xQbert I see, well is easy update with a regular expresion ;)

Comment: True. but you have to know all the rules, know what country your dealing with to apply the correct rules... and things change over time.  Good ideas and good starts but a complete solution I don't think's possible with the given details defiantly a good start but now you know why I say that this is not a silver bullet solution.

Comment: @xQbert Is ok I know what you mean, I do almost the same. I usually would leave those problems alone because additional rules appear after find the solution. But is friday so almost ready to go home :)